# Can you Cut Copy and Paste like this in Blender?

Tags: objects

I want to know if there's a quick and easy way to copy and paste faces or geo in general like I could in modo. I literally would press control C, Control v and paste or copy to my hearts content quickly. Is that possible in blender?

[image: Cut Copy and Pasting with ease]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can.

1. Select an object while in object mode
2. Switch to edit mode <kbd>Tab</kbd>
3. Switch to face select (<kbd>3</kbd> in 2.80)
4. Select faces that you want to duplicate. Use left click to select in Blender 2.80, right click in Blender 2.79b and earlier (hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> to select more than one face)
5. Duplicate selection <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
6. (Optional) Separate the selection into a new object using <kbd>P</kbd> > Selection

In object mode you can also duplicate entire objects using <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or copy and paste using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Comment: I'm in Blender 2.91 and I can't get this to work. I have a plane object in edit mode with its only face selected but ctrl + d doesn't seem to do anything. Ctrl + c does show a message saying I copied something, but i can't find any way to paste that. I'd like to keep the new plane with the original object.

Comment: @FedericoS It's *SHIFT* + d, not Ctrl.

Comment: Oh my god, I'm an idiot. x)  Thank you.